# MySQL query results are incorrect

Tags: mysql

im trying to update a table using this query:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE updateDataSetHasChildren()
BEGIN
    DECLARE data_set_id INT;
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE result INT DEFAULT FALSE;

    DECLARE data_set_cursor CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT id_data_set FROM data_set;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE; 

    OPEN data_set_cursor;

    myloop: LOOP
        -- Perform the first fetch.
        FETCH data_set_cursor into data_set_id;

        IF done THEN 
            LEAVE myloop;
        END IF;

        IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM data_sub_set WHERE id_data_set = data_set_id)>0 THEN
            UPDATE data_set
            SET has_children = TRUE
            WHERE id_data_set = data_set_id;
        ELSE
            UPDATE data_set
            SET has_children = FALSE 
            WHERE id_data_set = data_set_id;
        END IF;

        FETCH  data_set_cursor into data_set_id;
    END LOOP myloop;
    CLOSE data_set_cursor;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

The problem is that when i run it it fills the column of the table with 1 0 1 0 1 0...and when i check the values are incorrect, what am i missing here?

Regards,

Comment: That depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: For me is kind of obvious, im looping through the ids of table checking if they are used in another table, if they are i update the row corresponding to that id seting `has_children` as true

Comment: @Edu . . . What is obvious to you is not obvious (necessarily) to anyone else.  You have specified that the code *does not work*.  How are we supposed to know what working code is?  That is why explanations, sample data, and desired results improve such a question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff that is not correct, my code does work, it does not do what i want it to, it is just setting 1 an 0 again and again, what i was trying to say with my post is that i used variables and code kind of easy to read, if you understand MySQL you read it once and you can interpretate what im trying to do, if you dont, then the question is not for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove second

```
FETCH  data_set_cursor into data_set_id;
```

at the end of the `myloop`. Now it is working by steps:

1. Fetch id.
2. Process row.
3. Fetch id (loop end).
4. Fetch id (second loop iteration started).
5. Process row.
6. Fetch id.
7. Fetch id and so on...

Fetch is performed twice, and you are really processing every second row.